# Yodlee Rest API (coblogin) doesn't work with simple Rest Client

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to implement the Rest API for Yodlee using Spring RestTemplate.
For starter I'm trying to use the simple chrome extenuation to test the API but it doesn't seem to work.

(see image url here)

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/3c42d3fb-e69f-49c4-ab80-e4b607aca13e/03aea0e891c1f2c40414fcc992f2c307

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content type needs to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded and the request needs to be properly formatted.For example:

cobrandLogin=yourCobrandLogin&cobrandPassword=yourCobrandPassword

I've noticed that the error messages for the rest api are extremely unhelpful.

Comment: Yes, the could have at least say that they didn't get the parameters or something like it… Thanx for the help :) - sorry that I can't vote up - don't have the right score yet...